# Tornado redirect on cookie change

Tags: python, redirect, tornado

I'm using the Tornado server, where I change the currrent user to a new user and then I want to redirect to a certain page. Although the user has changed it doesn't redirect to this page and only does upon refreshing the browser page or navigating within the site.

This is the code fragment:

```
class SuperHandler(BaseHandler):
@tornado.web.authenticated
def post(self):
    self.clear_cookie("user")
    ................ 
    self.set_secure_cookie("user", new_user_id)

    self.redirect('/home')
```

In my console, it gives me a success message that redirect has occurred:

```
 [I 150226 19:19:55 web:1728] 200 GET /home (127.0.0.1) 356.00ms
```

How can I get the `self.redirect` to execute?

Answer (score 0):

The default HTTP status code for redirect in tornado is 302 (temporary redirect).  This is problematic for the POST method, as 302 would cause the post data to be resubmitted to a different URI.  User agents generally protect against this kind of behavior.  The HTTP 303 status was designed to handle redirection after a POST request, and the status can be set in the redirect method:

```
self.redirect('/home', status=303)
```

Comment: thanks but that still doesn't redirect to the home page.